# Datatables Custom Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

If the data in a given table is in a format that doesn't have a pre-built sorting plugin, how would I create and apply a custom sorting algorithm to a particular column using the datatables API? I read through the documentation, but found it a bit unwieldy.

Comment: check http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_sType.html

Comment: What are a & b in the function signature?

Comment: valueA and valueB, same as the 2 parameters in a normal sort function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: are a and b the html content of individual table cells within the targeted column? and if so, what if I want to sort based on a custom attribute defined on the parent elem, is that even possible?

Comment: mmm for dom access I think this one is better: http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Comment: awesome. thank you @juvian